# How to return the index of numpy ndarray based on search?

Tags: python, search, numpy, indexing

I have a numpy 2D array,

```
import numpy as np
array1 = array([[ 1,  2,  1,  1],
   [ 2,  2,  2,  1],
   [ 1,  1,  1,  1],
   [1,  3, 1, 1],
   [1,  1, 1, 1]])
```

I would like to find the element '3' and know its location. So, I could try

```
condition = array1 == 3
```

and then to find the arguments, I could try

```
np.argwhere(condition)
```

How else does one locate the indices where 3 is located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `where`, returning a tuple of coordinate:

```
In [34]: np.where(array1==3)
Out[34]: (array([3]), array([1]))
```