# Python, The fastest way to find numbers indexes in np. array

Tags: python

The fastest way to find numbers indexes in np. array in Python is?

Suppose we have a list of numbers from 0 to 20, and we want to know the indexes of digits 2 and 5

Comment: What have you tried? Did you measure the time? What does a profiler show?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the index of numpy ndarray based on search?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235546/how-to-return-the-index-of-numpy-ndarray-based-on-search)

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way would be to use numpy's `where` method:

```py
a = np.array(range(20))
np.where((a == 2) | (a == 5))
```

Note that in order to combine the two terms `(a == 2)` and `(a == 5)` we need the bitwise or operator `|`. The reason is that both `(a == 2)` and `(a == 5)` return a numpy array of `dtype('bool')`:

```
>>> a == 2
array([False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False])

>>> (a == 5)
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False])

>>> (a == 2) | (a==5)
array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False])
```